# Multi language website

Tags: seo

I have a multi language site, what is the way to proceed for good SEO for each language/ locale, right now i have:

```
<meta name="description" content=" ">
<meta name="Keywords" content=" ">
```

The site structure is : one domain, languages are switched within the file: php redraws the file according to the language selected by the user. So i thought i could switch the content of these meta's depending on the language selected by the user, am i on the right path?
thanks

Comment: I guess there are many ways of doing this. One simple method if you have many languages is to store the meta data within a DB table and load them depending on the language selected.

Comment: yes im not using a db but that's the idea, im wondering if the specific tags(for ex italian keywords) will (and only them) appear in italian google ( google.it), same thing for eng, fr etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how the user selects their language.  If it is a standard URL link robots shouldn't have a hard time crawling it.  If you're using some type of javascript or flash menu they may have a hard time indexing this dynamic content.

A bit of discussion on javascript and search engines can be found at:
http://www.websiteceo.com/articles/js-indexing.htm

Comment: yes it is a standard url(non Javascript), so having the metas switch into respective languages(for ex: if user selects italian the metas are populated with italian desc and italian keyword) would be of any help to get the italian keywords if the user is in google.it for example?

Answer (score 0):

This is almost identical to the question asked here [Internationalizing Title/Meta Tags ok or bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759774/internationalizing-title-meta-tags-ok-or-bad-practice/14804047#14804047) but instead of switching the language based on browser settings and the accept-language header, you are switching it based on a drop down.  You need to ensure that selecting this drop down **changes** the url.  You can't store languges in cookies and get good SEO results.

When googlebot crawls a page, it does not send any cookies.  You would either have to send it your default language, or ask it what language it wants (hint: it won't answer unless you give it a link to crawl).

For best SEO, use separate top level domains, subdomains, or folders for different languages.

---

- http://example.de/
- http://example.es/
- http://example.com/

---

- http://de.example.com/
- http://es.example.com/
- http://www.example.com/

---

- http://example.com/de/
- http://example.com/es/
- http://example.com/en/

Comment: Be aware of using subdomains that Google treats each separate subdomain as its own entity (different website)

Comment: That is a common misconception.  Google has the ability to treat subdomains as separate sites when they are owned by various people.  For example on blogspot.  However Google usually treats all subdomains as a single site.  For more information see [my answer to "Do Subdomains Help/Hurt SEO"](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/53923/) on Webmasters Stack Exchange.