# Internationalizing Title/Meta Tags ok or bad practice?

Tags: internationalization, seo

Is there a problem if I have both English and Chinese versions of the same title/meta tags under the same exact url? I detect the language the user has set for the browser (through the http header "accept-language" field) and change the titles/meta tags based on the language set. I get a large percentage of my traffic from China and felt this was a better-localized user experience for those users BUT I have no idea how Google would view this. My gut feeling tells me that this is not good for SEO.

Baidu.com, a major Chinese search engine, does in fact pick up my translated tags however for other US based sites it does not translate their English title/meta tags into Chinese. I would think Chinese users are less likely to click on those.

Creating sub domains and or separate domains for other countries is not an option at this point. That being said should I only have one language (English) for my title/meta tags to avoid any search engine issues?

Thanks for any advice / wisdom you can offer. Really hoping to get clarity on best practices.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it probably is a problem. Search engines see mixed language content. You are not describing how you “detect and change the titles/meta tags based on the users browser language”, but you are probably doing it client-side *and* using “browser language”, which is wrong whatever it means in detail (it does not specify the user’s preferred language).

To get a more targeted answer, ask a more real question, with a URL.

Comment: Thanks so much Jukka, I appreciate your insight! Do you think there could be a penalty from Google? I detect the language the user has set their browser to via the http header field "Accept-Language". I am unable to share a url at this time unfortunately.

Comment: So you are not actually detecting browser language but the user’s language preferences as set in a browser (which are almost always wrong in the sense of not reflecting the actual preferences, mostly just factory settings in a browser). Using them is OK in principle (known as “content negotiation”), mostly useless in practice. The problem is not with SEO. Indexing robots most probably don’t send any preferences, so they get whatever your server sends in such a case, normally a document containing links to the available alternatives, which is ok. Different versions get indexed with own URLs.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this Jukka.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get search traffic from search engines in both English and Chinese, you should have *two* urls instead of one.

When googlebot crawls a page, it does not even send the "Accept-Language" header.  You have to send it your default language.  When there is one url, there is no way for you to have your second language indexed.  You won't be ranked in search engines in multiple languages.

For best SEO, use separate top level domains, subdomains, or folders for different languages.

---

- http://example.de/
- http://example.es/
- http://example.com/

---

- http://de.example.com/
- http://es.example.com/
- http://www.example.com/

---

- http://example.com/de/
- http://example.com/es/
- http://example.com/en/

Answer (score 1):

I think there are no problem when you use English and Chinese in same meta tags.